# Проблемы combineLatest на angular7

Tags: angular

Вообщем у меня есть сервис:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Bill } from '../models/bill.model';


@Injectable
export class BillService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getBill(): Observable<Bill> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/bill');
    }

    getCurretncy(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=${this.apiKey}&symbols=RUB,USD,EUR`);
    }
}
```

И я делаю обращения к этим функциям так:

```
export class BillPageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private billService: BillService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = combineLatest(this.billService.getBill(), this.billService.getCurretncy()).subscribe((data: [Bill, any]) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Ну вообщем я ловлю вот такую ошибку на `@Injectable`:

```
Argument of type 'typeof BillService' is not assignable to parameter of type '({ providedIn: Type<any> | "root"; } & ValueSansProvider) | ({ providedIn: Type<any> | "root"; } & ExistingSansProvider) | ({ providedIn: Type<any> | "root"; } & StaticClassSansProvider) | ({ ...; } & ConstructorSansProvider) | ({ ...; } & FactorySansProvider) | ({ ...; } & ClassSansProvider)'.   Type 'typeof BillService' is not assignable to type '{ providedIn: Type<any> | "root"; } & ClassSansProvider'.     Type 'typeof BillService' is not assignable to type '{ providedIn: Type<any> | "root"; }'.       Property 'providedIn' is missing in type 'typeof BillService'.
```

Вообщем я прошу помощи дабы разобраться в этом хаосе.

Comment: `@Injectable()` - это фабрика, читайте, пожалуйста, документацию по DI в Angular, она описана на первых страницах

Comment: к тому же зачем вы засовываете http потоки в combinelatest + combinelatest в подписку, эти потоки закрываются автоматически после генерации события респонса....

Comment: Ну на данный момент я изучаю видео уроки, и эти самый уроки от angular4, вот и всё

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before

```
@Injectable
```

After

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
```